# How to draw a animated rectangle that implements some animations by using "Processing"

Tags: processing

a processing program that draws a rectangle in the top left of the window and moves it right until it is at the right edge of the screen.  Then move it down until it is at the bottom.  Then move it to the left.  Last, move it back to the top-left and start over.

Here is my unfinished code, I don't know how to let it move to the left when it hits the bottom line:

```java
void setup(){
size(500,500);
}
int x=0;
int y=0;
int dy=2;
int dx=2;
void draw(){


  x+=dx;


  if(x>=(width-50)){
    dx=0;
    y+=dy;
  } 
  if(y>=(height-50)){
    dy=0;
    x+=(-dx);
  }
  rect(x, y, 50,50, 7);
}
```

Comment: Two variables won't be enough. You will need left and right as well.

Comment: See this also: http://learningprocessing.com/examples/chp05/example-05-08-edgespath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution:

```
void setup(){
size(500,500);
}

int direction = 0;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

void draw(){

  switch (direction)
  {
     case 0: //Right
        x += 1;        
        if (x+50 >= width) direction = 1;
     break;

     case 1: //Down
        y += 1;        
        if (y+50 >= height) direction = 2;
     break;

     case 2: //Left
        x -= 1;        
        if (x <= 0) direction = 3;
     break;

     case 3: //Up
        y -= 1;        
        if (y <= 0) direction = 0;
     break;
   }

   rect(x, y, 50,50, 7);
}
```

I did not test it but I hope the general idea is clear.

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to mark the answer that most answers your question, so that other users can see that the problem was solved.

Comment: Minor error: x = 0 should be 'int x = 0' ; same for y=0.

Comment: Indeed it does, I changed it.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Titulum's answer I also recommend that you use objects as it makes life a lot easier than dealing with points the way you are.

```
Rectangle rect;
int direction;
int speed;

void checkDirections(){
switch (direction)
  {
     case 0: //Right
        rect.x += speed;        
        if (rect.x+rect.x1 >= width) direction = 1;
     break;

     case 1: //Down
        rect.y += speed;        
        if (rect.y+rect.y1 >= height) direction = 2;
     break;

     case 2: //Left
        rect.x -= speed;        
        if (rect.x <= 0) direction = 3;
     break;

     case 3: //Up
        rect.y -= speed;        
        if (rect.y <= 0) direction = 0;
     break;
   }
}


void setup(){
  size(500,500);
  direction = 0;
  speed = 5;
  rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50);
}

void draw(){
  background(255);
  checkDirections();
  rect.drawRect();
}

class Rectangle{
  float x,y,x1,y1;
  Rectangle(float x, float y, float x1, float y1){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.x1 = x1;
    this.y1 = y1;
  }
  void drawRect(){
    fill(0);
    rect(x,y,x1,y1);
  }
}
```